# Some unnecessery things appear on my donut model after rendering. How get rid of these?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

[image]

[image]

After rendering in Cycles engine these (circled in red). What is this? How do I get rid of these? In Eevee engine they do not appear.

Comment: Hello, maybe you have overlapping faces? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=lbSw5PRG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/lbSw5PRG/)

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping faces, which creates artefacts (it is called *Z fighting*), in *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*:

[image]

Comment: That didn't help( What distance should I set?

Comment: @artiom ligay see my edit, it seems to work, no?

Comment: Didn't see your GIF. That worked. Thank you! I'm very new at Blender and didnt understand correctly what exactly to do.